# Loop to search every row of 914 rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a data range of 14 dates:
[image]

This goes until 914 rows.

I need a loop, where you enter a date if prompted, and if it's in the select range (per each row), then it would jump to the corresponding row in Column B.

The following will search for the date inputted, only in row 2 (columns y through l). I need this configured like an array almost, where it would search through each row of the 914 rows, and jump to the corresponding spot in the row.

Tried this:

```vb
Sub FindABC()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim b As Range
    Set b = Range("A2")
    Set rng = Range("L2:Y2]").Find(What:=InputBox("Enter Date", "Enter a Date"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        b.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Set rng = Range("L2:Y916").Find(...)`  ?

Comment: ...and then `If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Range("B1").Select`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if the find function is not working well for your use case with all these lines:

```
i=2
While Range("L" & i).value <> ""
    Set rng = Range("L" & i & ":Y" & i).Find(What:=InputBox("Enter Date", "Enter a Date"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        b.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
   i=i+1
   if i>1000 then exit sub
Wend
```

Comment: What's that `"]"` ?

Comment: Indeed, just copy pasted the original code, no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think either we don't understand your problem or you THINK you have a problem that currently there really isn't.

You say "I need it to look in x row, between I and Y columns... if found, just to corresponding row's cell Bx".

Does that mean it's not allowed to search for this date in other rows? Does that mean each row you want to enter a new date to test if it's found in this row?

If you simply CAN search through all rows between columns I and Y (not just 1 row),
then you can just change this line:

```
Set rng = Range("L2:Y2]").Find(What:=InputBox("Enter Date", "Enter a Date"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

To

```
Set rng = Range("L2:Y914]").Find(What:=InputBox("Enter Date", "Enter a Date"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

(only changed Y2 to Y914)

Then you can get that range's row with

```
target_row = rng.Row
```

Then you can jump to column B and that row with:

```
Cells(target_row, target_col).Select
```

Here's the full code:

```
Sub FindABC()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim target As Range
    target_col = 2 ' 2 = B in columns count
    find_this = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Date", Title:="Enter a Date")
    Set rng = Range("A2:Y914")
    Set target = rng.Find(What:=find_this, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not target Is Nothing Then
        target_row = target.Row
        Cells(target_row, target_col).Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Let me know if I misunderstood you.